# Выдается TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python-3.x, django

Я новичок в django и python в целом, делал сайт по гайдам, но в один момент, при попытке освоить шаблонизацию, выдало ошибку TemplateDoesNotExist. Скрин прилагается, расположение папок и весь код прилагается. Если что-то еще нужно докинуть - напишите. Только прошу найти ошибку, мне важно освоить это, а в чем ошибка я, после двухчасовых поисков, так и не разобрался
[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]
+
РАСПОЛОЖЕНИЕ ПАПОК:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

VIEWS.PY:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'first/list.html'),
```

SETTINGS.PY:

```
    """
Django settings for universal project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first.apps.FirstConfig',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'universal.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'universal.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('first/', include('first.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), # grappelli URLS
]
```

LIST.HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Последние статьи{% endblock %}}
{% block content %}

    Я афлдалалфжладжфлджалф ...

{% endblock  %}
```

BASE.HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Мой сайт{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Папка templates  должна лежать в папке first, а у тебя она на одном уровен с  ней. Т.е джанго пытается найти first/templates/first/...